# Open file downloaded within React-Native app with another app

Tags: react-native

I am trying to open files (images, pdfs, videos, etc) downloaded with my React-Native app from my server.

So I'm using `RNFetchBlob` to download the file then I'm doing the following depending if it's an iOS or Android device:

```
openFile = (item, path) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      RNFetchBlob.ios.previewDocument(path)
    } else {
      // I've tried setting a real mimetype instead of / but it still doesn't work
      RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(path, '/')
    }
}
```

On iOS it works as expected but nothing happens on Android even though I have apps that can read images, pdfs or videos on the device I'm testing on.

Any ideas why this doesn't work or how I could make the same thing with another library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE:

The PR has been merged back in 09/2019 so it should work properly and the answer below should be ignored.

---

Found out the reason for this, it's a know bug of the library and has a PR waiting to be merged (no timeframe from the repo owner).
Here is the link to the PR: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/pull/317

So basically this needs to be added to line 122-123 of file `android/src/main/java/com/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlob.java`:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

If above is not working do to the below step:
overwrite the 121 line in `android/src/main/java/com/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlob.java`:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // 121 line
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // 122 line
```

Comment: I am trying to save files in File App of iOS device but unable to do that. Which directory path you have used to save files on iOS.

Comment: Doing this, it started showing the list of the apps to open the file. But still, the file doesn't get open in Android 10. Perhaps, something wrong with the way Android 10 manages file path.

Comment: @NarendraSingh Hmm..Does it work on other versions of Android ? Maybe it is related to permissions ? Haven't used RN and this for some time now so can't tell.

Comment: @Moucheg yes, it was working in other versions. And now worked in Android 10 as well, just by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @NarendraSingh You shouldn't be using that as it is only a temporary thing that will be ignored by Android 11.

Please have a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage

Sorry that I can't be of more help, I gave up working with ReactNative after 1 project.. It's not worth the headaches and time spent on stupid issues like this all the time. Plus native is way better for my personal growth and satisfaction

Answer (score 0):

Since its working in July 2023, here I am leaving a reply

Note: Make sure the mime type is correct.

```
const mimeType = mime.lookup(fileName);
if (mimeType) {
    android.actionViewIntent(configOptions.path, mimeType);
}
```

For getting mimeType in react-native, I am using [react-native-mime-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mime-types) package.